# How to get PUT and DELETE parameters from HTTPRequest in SilverStripe?

Tags: ajax, rest, silverstripe, put

There are getVars(), postVars() and requestVars() methods in HTTPRequest.
They returns parameters from GET and POST requests.

But how can I get parameters from PUT and DELETE requests?

I know that there is a 'body' property somewhere in HTTPRequest. It contains PUT params in query string or something similar.
To use this property I need to parse 'body' field.

Is there a way to get these parameters with comfortable way, like for GET and POST?

Comment: Worth noting that in PHP POST and GET don't have that much to do with their HTTP methods. 'GET' variables are available for every method. The 'GET' and 'POST' in php are actually named after the 'method' attribute in HTML forms.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do it the old school way.

```
parse_str($request->getBody(), $params);
$foo = $params['Foo'];
```

Keep in mind the second parameter of `parse_str` is a reference, so no need to define that variable before invoking the function call.